# Function to save more values from same cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have some cells that saves more values. An example could be

250;3;1

Where 250 is the product number, 3 is the amount of that product and 1 is the status of the product. I would like to use these values in an Excel VBA macro. So I for example gets these values:

```
Dim ProdNum as Long
Dim Amount as Long
Dim Status As Long

ProdNum = 250 (product number)
Amount = 3
Status = 1
```

Are there any smart way to do this, or do I have to use a find function or something like that?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why are you jamming multiple values into a single variable?  What is the source for this input?

Comment: The smart way would probably be to use `Text to Columns` to split each data point into separate columns

Comment: If you know they're separated by a delimiter - In this case a ";", bring in the text, break it apart yourself into the 3 elements in your code and assign each part to the corresponding variable....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
Sub Several()
    Dim ProdNum As Long, Amount As Long, Status As Long
    arry = Split([A1], ";")
    ProdNum = arry(0)
    Amount =  arry(1)
    Status =  arry(2)
End Sub
```

Comment: Great. That was exactly what I needed. Thank you very much.